# Border of Div with 100% dimensions isn't displayed

Tags: css, stylesheet, border

Consider this simple markup:

```
<body>
 <div style="border: 2px solid navy; position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%">
 </div>
</body>
```

In the browsers I've tested (Firefox and Chrome) the right and the bottom parts of the border seem to lie outside the window area, since they are not visible. How should I fix my markup or stylesheet so that the div's border is completely visible while the div occupies the whole available area (i.e. its sizes are 100%/100% or equivalent)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the border rests outside of the width of an element, if your body width is 100%, the border will be outside of that and thus not visible. Take a look at the box model:

[alt text http://www.codeweblog.com/upload/b/basic-knowledge-of-css.png](http://www.codeweblog.com/upload/b/basic-knowledge-of-css.png)

To set a border for your page, just don't define the width and height:

```
body
{
  border: 2px solid navy;
}
```

---

An alternative would be to do a faux border, setting the HTML background color to your border color, adding some padding, and then setting your body to the normal page background color:

```
html
{
  background-color: navy;
  padding: 2px;
}
body
{
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Or if you are wanting to accomplish this using a `div`:

```
<body>
  <div class="containerDiv">
    <div class="theDiv">
      Content here.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

...

div.containerDiv
{
  background-color: navy;
  padding: 2px;
}
div.theDiv
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks e.c.ho, I added some more code to directly answer his question.

Comment: @Jaffar, look at the end of the post for a `div` solution.

Comment: @Jaffar, take a look at the last example now.